# Example of a Noetherian local ring of dimension one which is not a discrete valuation ring.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension, local-rings

What is the example of a Noetherian local ring of dimension one which is not a discrete valuation ring.

Answer (score 2):

Take the local ring of any curve singularity, for instance localize $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$ at $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ring of polynomials over a noetherian local ring with Krull dimension 0, say $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$, localised at the maximal ideal $\langle (p\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z, X\rangle$. Or the ring of formal power series over the same ring.

Comment: I suppose that "integral domain" is somehow implicit.